# Deploying a Django app to Weblogic: Cannot find modjy

Tags: django, weblogic-10.x

I'm trying to deploy a django app to Weblogic and it cannot find modjy. I looked in the jython.jar that is included in the generated war file, and the modjy servlet is indeed there. Below is  the error the server gets when deploying the app.

```
<Feb 18, 2010 11:18:49 AM EST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "modjy" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "myApp.war".
Traceback (innermost last):
File "<string>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: no module named modjy

    at org.python.core.Py.ImportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_first(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_name(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.imp.importName(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.ImportFunction.load(Unknown Source)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Feb 18, 2010 11:18:49 AM EST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the     activation state to true for the application 'myApp'.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "modjy" failed to preload     on startup in Web application: "myApp.war".
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: no module named modjy

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1399)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:460)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: no module named modjy

    at org.python.core.Py.ImportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_first(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_name(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.imp.importName(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.ImportFunction.load(Unknown Source)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Comment: I've been experiencing a really similar problem: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm not sure if this is a problem with Django on Jython or a problem with weblogic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for getting to this issue so late: I just spotted the URL in my referer logs.

The problem here is that modjy is failing to import the "modjy.py" module, which lives in the jython Lib/modjy directory.

I have created a "Modjy Troubleshooting" page, and described this problem on it.

http://opensource.xhaus.com/projects/modjy/wiki/ModjyTroubleShooting

If that doesn't solve the problem, then please send an email to the jython-users list.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the instructions at the [modjy wiki](http://opensource.xhaus.com/projects/modjy/wiki)?

It looks like WebLogic can't find that library, so it looks like something was missed in the steps to set it up. You never gave any info on how you did your set up, so it's hard to tell.